# jQuery validation addMethod element convert to a string

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod( "multi_select", function( value, element , params ) {

 var string = element.toString();
 console.log(string);

}, 'Please select atleast one element.');
```

I want to get the element value as a string. How can i do this ??

Comment: what do you mean by element as a string.. do you want the element's value?

Comment: yes, i want the element value as a string .

Comment: Use `element.innerHTML`

Comment: that will be first parameter to the validate method

Comment: @RaviShakya  You need the value of that `element`?

Comment: element.innerHTML doesn't exactly get what i want. the element will return <select name="address"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>. element.innerHTML will only get <option>1</option><option>2</option>. But I dont want that i only want <select name="address"></select>. How can i do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check at least one item is selected in a multi select element then just use the required rule

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      multi: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <select name="multi" multiple>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

---

But if you want to implement your own logic, the `value` parameter passed to the method will be the value of the input/select element, in case of a multi select element it will be an array(null if no item is selected) so

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("multi_select", function(value, element, params) {
  console.log(value)
  return value && value.length > 0
}, 'Please select atleast one element.');

jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      multi: {
        multi_select: true
      }
    },
    messages: {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
  <select name="multi" multiple>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```